# Restoring old database in Mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, restore

I am trying to restore an old database (from 2009) using phpMyAdmin. I get the following error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'not_null primary_key auto_increment, `Owned` int(11) not_null, `Owner` int' at line 2
```

I googled the error but couldn't find a solution. I understand something has changed with MySQL over years, but what should i do?

My query is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `aautod` (
    `aAutoId` int(11) not_null primary_key auto_increment, 
    `Owned` int(11) not_null, 
    `Owner` int(11) not_null, 
    `Description` string(64) not_null, 
    `Model` int(11) not_null, 
    `Value` int(11) not_null, 
    `Locked` int(11) not_null, 
    `ColorOne` int(11) not_null, 
    `ColorTwo` int(11) not_null, 
    `License` string(100) not_null, 
    `Locationx` real(12) not_null, 
    `Locationy` real(12) not_null, 
    `Locationz` real(12) not_null, 
    `Angle` real(12) not_null, 
    `Parked` real(12) not_null, 
    `ParkLocationx` real(12) not_null, 
    `ParkLocationy` real(12) not_null, 
    `ParkLocationz` real(12) not_null, 
    `ParkAngle` real(12) not_null, 
    `GPS` int(11) not_null, 
    `Color1` int(11) not_null, 
    `Color2` int(11) not_nul, 
    PRIMARY KEY (`aAutoId`)
) TYPE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: not_null to  `not null` and primary_key to 'primary key'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple errors:

As has already been pointed out `not_null` should be `not null`. As well as `primary_key` should be `primary key`.

I changed `string(xx)` to `varchar`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//string-types.html

`real(xx)` takes two arguments, not 1. The second argument is how many decimals places are after the decimal point.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/floating-point-types.html

`type=MyISAM` was changed to `Engine=MyIsam`

You also defined your primary key twice, once on the first line declaration and on the last line of the table declaration. I changed to this to declare it only once.

```
CREATE TABLE `aautod` (
`aAutoId` int(11) not null primary key auto_increment, 
`Owned` int(11) not null, 
`Owner` int(11) not null, 
`Description` varchar(64) not null, 
`Model` int(11) not null, 
`Value` int(11) not null, 
`Locked` int(11) not null, 
`ColorOne` int(11) not null, 
`ColorTwo` int(11) not null, 
`License` varchar(100) not null, 
`Locationx` real(12,11) not null, 
`Locationy` real(12,11) not null, 
`Locationz` real(12,11) not null, 
`Angle` real(12,11) not null, 
`Parked` real(12,11) not null, 
`ParkLocationx` real(12,11) not null, 
`ParkLocationy` real(12, 11) not null, 
`ParkLocationz` real(12, 11) not null, 
`ParkAngle` real(12, 11) not null, 
`GPS` int(11) not null, 
`Color1` int(11) not null, 
`Color2` int(11) not null
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Thanks, i made those changes but now i got :  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1' at line 35

Comment: What version of phpmyadmin and mysql are you using? I just ran the query with phpmyadmin 3.4 and MySQL 5.5 and it worked. Its most likely a version problem. Try changing it back to type-MyISAM

Comment: My MySQL version is 5.1.66 protocol 10 and phpmyadmin is 3.5.4, even if i change it back same error.   Thanks for your help.

Comment: I also tried on other server with Mysql 5.5 and phpmyadmin 3.5.1

Comment: Sorry I can't help more, I just ran it on 2 different servers and I couldn't reproduce your error. I'm not sure what the problem is. According to this:http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/myisam-storage-engine.html. Engine = MYISAM should work And according to this page - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-mysql.html - latin1 is a valid charset. I hoped I at least pointed you in the right direction on how to fix the query.

Answer (score 0):

it should be two separate words: `NOT NULL`, `PRIMARY KEY`.